# I don't know why this code keeps getting t_string error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I think I am doing everything right but I keep getting a t_string error in the code.  I will show what line.  If anyone can figure this out, I would be very greatful.  I did do research on quotes, and am thinking maybe the data in the database has something to do with the error since it includes the @ symbol and period.

The error is at line 76 which is `if(empty($row['email']))`

The entire code is

```
ini_set("include_path", ".:/public_html/phpmailer"); //Used for simplicity
include("mysql_connect.php"); //The database name, login, etc..
set_error_handler("customError"); //I created a custom error

$login = 'username@domain.com';
$password = 'password';
$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/novalidate-cert}';
$connection = imap_open($server, $login, $password);

$mailboxinfo = imap_mailboxmsginfo($connection);
$messageCount = $mailboxinfo->Nmsgs; //Number of emails in the inbox
for ($MID = 1; $MID <= $messageCount; $MID++)
  {
  $EmailHeaders = imap_headerinfo($connection, $MID); //Save all of the header information
  $Body = imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($connection, $MID, 1)); //The body of the email to be forwarded
  $MessageSentToAllArray = $EmailHeaders->to; //Grab the “TO” header
  $MessageSentToAllObject = $MessageSentToAllArray[0];
  $MessageSentToMailbox = $MessageSentToAllObject->mailbox; //Everything before the “@” of the recipient
  $MessageSentToHost = $MessageSentToAllObject->host; //Everything after the “@” of the recipient
  $MessageSentFromAllArray = $EmailHeaders->from; //Grab the “FROM” header
  $MessageSentFromAllObject = $MessageSentFromAllArray[0];
  $MessageSentFromMailbox = $MessageSentFromAllObject->mailbox; //Everything before the “@” of the sender
  $MessageSentFromHost = $MessageSentFromAllObject->host; //Everything after the “@” of the sender
  $MessageSentFromName = $MessageSentFromAllObject->personal; //The name of the person who sent the email
  $toArray = searchRecipient($MessageSentToMailbox); //Find the correct person to send the email to
  if($toArray == FALSE) //If the alias they entered doesn’t exist…
    {
    $bounceback = 'Sorry the email in your message does not appear to be correct';
    /* Send a bounceback email */
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php “mail()”
    $mail -> ContentType = ‘text/plain’; //Plain email
    $mail -> IsHTML(false); //No HTML
    $the_body = wordWrap($bounceback, 70); //Word wrap to 70 characters for formatting
    $from_email_address = 'Support@domain.com';
    $mail->AddReplyTo($from_email_address, "Domain.Com");
    $mail->SetFrom($from_email_address, "Domain.Com");
    $address = "$MessageSentFromMailbox@$MessageSentFromHost"; //Who we’re sending the email to
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $MessageSentFromName);
    $mail->Subject = 'WAHM Link Request'; //Subject of the email
    $mail->Body = $the_body;
    if(!$mail->Send()) //If the mail fails, send to customError
      {
      customError(1, $mail->ErrorInfo, "anon-email.php", "sending the email");
      }
    }
  else //If the candidate address exists, forward on the email
    {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php “mail()”
    $mail -> ContentType = ‘text/plain’; //Plain E-mail
    $mail -> IsHTML(FALSE); //No HTML
    $the_body = wordwrap($Body, 70); //Wordwrap for proper email formatting
    $from_email_address = "$MessageSentFromMailbox@$MessageSentFromHost";
    $mail->AddReplyTo($from_email_address, $MessageSentFromName);
    $mail->SetFrom($from_email_address, $MessageSentFromName);
    $address = $toArray[1]; //Who we’re sending the email to
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $toArray[0]); //The name of the person we’re sending to
    $mail->Subject = $EmailHeaders->subject; //Subject of the email
    $mail->Body = ($the_body);
    if(!$mail->Send()) //If mail fails, go to the custom error
      {
      customError(1, $mail->ErrorInfo, "anon-email.php", "sending the email");
      }
    }
  /* Mark the email for deletion after processing */
  imap_delete($connection, $MID);
  }
  imap_expunge($connection); // Expunge processes all of the emails marked to be deleted
  imap_close($connection);

  function searchRecipient() // function to search the database for the real email
{
    global $MessageSentToMailbox; // bring in the alias email
    $email_addr = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM tbl WHERE source='$MessageSentToMailbox'"); // temp store of the real email
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($email_addr); //making temp store of data for use in program
    if(empty($row['email']))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else  /* Else, return find the person's name and return both in an array */
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE email = '$email_addr'"; // pulling in the row where the emails match
        $results = mysql_query($query, $email_addr); // temp store of both queries from this function
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results); //making temp store of data for use in program
        $name = $row['author'];  // taking the author data and naming its variable
        return array($name, $email_addr);  // this is the name and the real email address to be used in function call
    }
}

function customError($errno, $errstr, $file, $line)
{
    error_log("Error: [$errno] $errstr in $file at line number: $line",1, "name@domain.com","From: name@domain.com");   
    die();
}
```

Comment: I get no syntax errors running `php -l` on this code.

Comment: @Michael Did you add a `<?php`? I actually do get the same error parsed with 5.3.8

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes, 5.3.10 and no error.

Comment: Could you paste the exact error?

Comment: I'm not getting an error on 5.3.6

Comment: You sure that the $row is filled with the resource? I mean maybe the SQL expression is somehow wrong. Maybe it's better to `var_dump` the $row itself.

Comment: Can you echo `$row['email']` before the line that errors?

Comment: @Michael Turns out it's (sort of) my bad that your version parses, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It has taken me quite a long time to figure this out, not least because it seems that stackoverflow has corrected the problem for you. There are a number of `0xA0` characters littered randomly through your source code (my editor counts 33) in the middle of white-space blocks. The PHP parser is obviously not liking these very much and throwing an error.

I have just done a find/replace in my editor to convert them all to spaces (`0x20`) and it now parses.

It seems that I spoiled it for everybody with my first edit of your question, as SO corrected the problem then and I now can't repeat it by copying the code as it is currently displayed, despite rolling back to the original version - sorry everyone.

If you copy and paste the above code back into your editor, the problem disappeared. StackOverflow has actively fixed the problem.

Comment: +1 For SO gaining the intelligence and self-awareness to start correcting code on its own.

Comment: Now if only we could teach it to insert `mysql_real_escape_string()` calls into n00b PHP code or refactor into PDO...

Comment: @Michael lol, or to point out missing curly braces. If your interested, [here](http://pastebin.com/bwYUbAq9) is a paste of the original corrupted data - pastebin seems to play the game with not altering it

Comment: LOL.  OK, I will try this.  Thanks for taking your time.  I still don't know what you meant however by 0xA0.  If you can explain that and what went wrong here so that I can prevent it in the future, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @EmilyBonilla I am referring to the fact that there were a number of characters in the file that were being represented by the byte `0xa0` - this is the [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), the same character that is represented by the HTML entity `&nbsp;`. I have no idea how they leaked into your file, most editors will never use them, they should use the standard space `0x20`. Which editor/IDE do you use for writing you code?

Comment: @DaveRandom Thank you Dave for your explanation.  I get it now.  I did take the bits of code from a webpage and I also pasted some in my Evernote before using in Dreamweaver.  Lots of copy and paste through different programs which probably caused this.  However, I wish Dreamweaver would have told me when I ran a validation check.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the error, but you have fancy single quotes here:

`$mail -> ContentType = ‘text/plain’; //Plain email`

It actually appears since twice in your code.